# Which type of data sqlite3 select returns in python?

Tags: python, sqlite, select, cs50

Can someone please help me to understand what this `db.execute` line returns? In databases it returns rows but when we assign this `db.execute` to a python variable what it returns actually? I tried to treat the result as a list and also as a dictionary but both are such confusing. When I try to extract data as a list, i get dictionary error and when i try to extract data as a dict i get list errors, so how can I manipulate the `cash` variable? TIA

list version:

```
cash_list = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE username = ?", owner_id)
        
        cash = cash_list[0][0]

        if cash < total: 
            return apology("don't have enough cash")
        else:
            left = cash - total
            db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ?", left)
```

list version compiler error:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/pset8/finance/helpers.py", line 34, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/pset8/finance/application.py", line 85, in buy
    cash = cash_list[0][0]
KeyError: 0
```

dictionary version:

```
cash_dict = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE username = ?", owner_id)

        cash = cash_dict["cash"]

        if cash < total:
            return apology("don't have enough cash")
        else:
            left = cash - total
            db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ?", left)
```

dictionary version compiler error:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/pset8/finance/helpers.py", line 34, in decorated_function
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/pset8/finance/application.py", line 85, in buy
        last_cash = cash_dict["cash"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: can you execute len(cash_dict) , and tell what is your output

Comment: According to the [sqlite3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) `execute` returns a `Cursor` object. Try using `Cursor().fetchall()` to fetch all (remaining) rows of a query result in list format.

Comment: @SandrinJoy sorry but couldn't do it because program gives error after the initiliazing `cash` so it doesn't execute

Comment: @cetins why do you have to initialize cash ? i am asking about cash_dict . put it after line 1. and execute

Comment: @SandrinJoy sorry i didn't initiliaze cash I wrote the line like this: 
cash_dict = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE username = ?", owner_id)

        x = len(cash_dict)

Comment: @SandrinJoy then I tried to find a way to see that value on page but it doesnt print out. I was trying to do that still couldn't figure out :/

Comment: @SandrinJoy ok finally I got it, the length is 1

Comment: now do print(cash_dict) after line 1 , and tell the o/p

Comment: @SandrinJoy [{'cash': 10000}] so it's a dictionary in a list?

Comment: Yes,in python terms it can be called a dict. But i think it is json formatted data .if you read the comments, you can see how i did the debugging. You can try this kind of steps whenever u get some variable error

Comment: @SandrinJoy I tried to manipulate data as a dictionary in a list and could finally execute without errors. Sincerely thanks, not just the solution but also for the mindset !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here , I'm giving the solution again to make this question as solved

```
 cash = cash_list[0]['cash']
```

This gives you the o/p which you were looking for.

For example ,if  `[{'cash':10000}]` is the data returned , then the `cash_list[0]['cash']`  gives the value `10000`